# CSS and the toils of developing for IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

Just finishing up the development of a site, but what would website development be without the occasional head-hitting-desk feeling of trying to get things to work in Internet Explorer..specifically IE8 in this case. Check out the following page. It's working fine in Chrome, IE9 and 10, and Firefox; IE8 is the last one is has to be working for. `http://dev.mrstore.co.uk/container-sales-hire.php`. I've been trying to get it work by floating the elements..I've tried a clear:both after the third image..set height and width..I dunno. It might be a combination of things, but at this point, I wouldn't mind having a push in the right direction. I just want to get this last bug fixed.

Comment: have you tried the developer tools in IE8?  ( http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/09/03/developer-tools-in-internet-explorer-8-beta-2.aspx)

Comment: You know, I've always used IE to develop in. Sure it meant I was late adopting `border-radius` and similar features only added in IE9, but by God has it saved me a lot of headdesking!

Comment: Your html is not valid, fix that first.

Comment: Yes, I've tried the developer tools for IE8. I'm still toying around with it, but haven't gotten very far with it..yet. 

@Zippy, is there something huge wrong with it? According to the w3c validator, it's only a few list items that are off. Unfortunately, I can't do much to solve this as I'm using some php in that same section to help with the formatting of the sidebar. Should still render fine, right? I've looked in the code for any extra brackets of quotes, but there's nothing. Not sure how much time it's worth trying to fix something that works fine.

Comment: the link for self storage tips doesnt close the list item, its closing an i element. validation is the key for cross-browser goodness.

Comment: Oops, you're right. That's corrected, and now the site is classified as XHTML 1.0 Transitional. Unfortunately, IE8 still isn't playing nice. :(

Comment: You are also using the same id on multiple elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML code is broken. You are missing the ending tags for the links around the last four images.

Comment: Thank you! It's amazing how the smallest things can completely break a webpage. It's also funny how every other modern browser is able to render it correctly.

Comment: @user1318340: Well, rendering it correctly would actually be to refuse to render it at all... When a browser finds incorrect code it tries to create elements from it anyway using some kind of guessing algorithm, which differs from browser to browser. Some browsers just happens to create the elements the same way that you intended to write the code.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the tip. I'll make damn sure to check every closing element from now on...that's for sure. :p